# Get font name and color of an image using java

Tags: java, user-interface, colors, fonts

I am presently running an automation UI test, part of the checks is to make sure the background color, font color and the font-family used are consistent throughout the app. The code takes a snapshot of screen or element and checks the background color, but I'm unable to check the font-family and font color. I have a code to check the background color, which works great. Is there a way to get the font-family and color? Is there any Java library that does that?

I have attached a sample image. The image background color is white that is detected by the code below.

This code checks the background-color

```
public void checkBackgroundColor(String mobileElement, String saveReadFile, String hexValue) throws IOException {
        MobileElement elem = (MobileElement) getMobileDriver().findElement(By.xpath(mobileElement));
        File scrFile = elem.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File(saveReadFile));
        File savedFile = new File(saveReadFile);
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read( savedFile);
        org.openqa.selenium.Point point = elem.getCenter();
        org.openqa.selenium.Point location = elem.getLocation();
        Dimension size = elem.getSize();

        MyLogger.info("Point X is  " + point.getX() +"    Point Y is  " + point.getY());
        MyLogger.info("Location X is  " + location.getX() +"   Location Y is  " + location.getY());
        MyLogger.info("Size Height is  " + size.getHeight() +"   Size width is  " + size.getWidth());

        // Getting pixel color by position x and y
        int h = (int) Math.round(size.getWidth() * 0.2);
        int w = (int) Math.round(size.getHeight() * 0.8);
        int clr=  image.getRGB(h , w);
        int  r   = (clr & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
        int  g = (clr & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
        int  b =  clr & 0x000000ff;

        String hex = String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", r, g, b);
        if (hex.equalsIgnoreCase(hexValue)){
            MyLogger.info("Actual value  "+ hexValue +"   of  " +buttons+savedFile.getName()  +"  is equals to the expected value  " +hex);
        } else {
            MyLogger.info("Actual value  "+ hexValue  +"   of  " +buttons+savedFile.getName() +"  is is not equals to the expected value  " +hex);
        }
    }
```

[image: font color and family]

Comment: Did my suggestion work for you?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Though it returned dialog as the font name, the font in practice is Ubuntu Bold. I wonder why it's not reading it as such.

Comment: Yeah, I am not sure why. I will do a bit more digging and will update the answer if I find anything.

Comment: Thanks a lot @hfontanez

Comment: Are you running this code on an Ubuntu or in Windows?

Comment: This is a mystery. I ran code that set the font on the `Graphics2D` object to _Serif_ and yet, when I queried the `BufferedImage` object to give me the font name set in the object, it still returns _Dialog_. Funny thing is that _Serif_ is one of the logical fonts in Java, so I don't get why it will fail.

Comment: I am asking this question... This is bothering me too much.

Comment: Ist there any particula reason for doing it with a screenshot? Why do you not read the font from the webpage itself through the Selenium Driver?

Comment: @ken4ward I just asked this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70882734/font-face-value-returns-unexpected-value-dialog-from-image. Check out the comments. It's a nightmare!

Comment: @ken4ward you won't be able to access the Font information unless you save it yourself. Read the link to the question I asked. I posted an answer myself. It simply can't be done.

Comment: @hfontanez Thanks a lot. Actually, I'm running Appium mobile test that cannot access the. information directly, that's the reason I used to try to analyze screenshots.

Comment: I see. The reason it's made private got me thinking, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
Graphics g = image.getGraphics(); //using the BufferedImage from your example
System.out.println(g.getFont().getFamily()); // For me, it displays "Dialog" which is one of the logical fonts according to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/fonts.html
g.dispose();
```

**UPDATE**:

`image.getGraphics()` doesn't return the `Graphics2D` object that was used to create the overlay. It actually creates a new graphics object and returns it. Two of the subclasses of `Graphics2D` actually hold a delegate object that apparently holds this info. Unfortunately, these subclasses of `Graphics2D` are in the `sun` package which is now restricted. Therefore, this information seems to be inaccessible. If you require the `Font` that was used for the overlay, you may have no choice but to cache this information in some "overlay config" object.