# Font face value returns unexpected value ("Dialog") from image

Tags: java, bufferedimage, graphics2d

This code snippet creates an image which contains text. I set the font to *Serif*. However, when I query the resulting image later on for its font face, it returns *Dialog*. I don't understand why this is.

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(200, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 200, 100, this); // "this" refers to my custom JPanel which I am setting in the JFrame. 
g2d.setPaint(Color.red);
g2d.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
System.out.println("from g2d object: " + g2d.getFont().getFamily()); // outputs "Serif"
String s = "Hello, world!";
FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
int x = img.getWidth() - fm.stringWidth(s) - 5;
int y = fm.getHeight();
g2d.drawString(s, x, y);
g2d.dispose();
System.out.println("from image: " + img.getGraphics().getFont().getFamily()); // outputs "Dialog" (expected "Serif")
```

I understand that *Dialog* is one of the logical fonts in Java, but if the font is set to be something else, and `Font.getFontName()` returns the *font face* for the given font, why isn't it returning *Serif* as set in the `Graphics2D` object?

**UPDATE**: Calling `g2d.dispose()` before or after the last `System.out.println()` makes no difference. Both ways, it still prints out *Dialog*.

Comment: @user16320675 I tried that first and made no difference.

Comment: @user16320675 you are guessing. Read what the method `dispose()` does. It releases resources used by that graphics object. If I set a font in a graphics object, the expectation is that it should remain for the life of that (graphics) object. Later on, if I get a reference of that image, I should be able to "ask" the object things about itself (i.e. background color, foreground color, what font is used in its overlay, etc.). I can get the color used for the text, but not the font name or font face.

Comment: Do `g2,dispose()` after the last `System.out.println`. As `Serif` is not a logical font, font substitutions happens after cleaning up `g2`.

Comment: @JoopEggen that is how I originally wrote it. I was still getting _Dialog_. That's when I decided to call `dispose()` before the last `System.out`.

Comment: @JoopEggen you are also incorrect about _Serif_ not being a logical font. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/fonts.html

Comment: I think I found the answer!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL:DR** The font is not accessible in `Graphics` or `Graphics2D`.

Whether you invoke `BufferedImage#createGraphics()` directly or `BufferedImage#getGraphics()` the end result is the same: they both create a new graphics object. More specifically, the former returns a new `Graphics` object and the latter returns a `Graphics2D` object. Both are abstractions of the concrete type returned which is an instance of `SunGraphics2D`. Unfortunately, this object does not store any information set, **related to the font**, in the graphics object. So basically, I cannot get the data I need from the image object.

In contrast, `ProxyGraphics2D` and `PeekGraphics` - both subtypes of the abstract class `Graphics2D` class do store such information in a `Graphics2D` global variable called `mGraphics`. This object is accessed via the `getDelegate()` method, which is obviously **not** part of the `Graphics` or `Graphics2D` API. Unfortunately, both of these subclasses are part of the `sun` package which is no longer accessible. Examining these classes clearly shows that methods like `setFont()` do save the font in this delegate (`Graphics2D`) object.

Answer (score 1):

`BufferedImage.getGraphics()` returns the result of `BufferedImage.createGraphics()`. And, following the trail, we end up at that method of `SunGraphicsEnvironment`:

```java
   /**
     * Returns a Graphics2D object for rendering into the
     * given BufferedImage.
     * @throws NullPointerException if BufferedImage argument is null
     */
    public Graphics2D createGraphics(BufferedImage img) {
        if (img == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("BufferedImage cannot be null");
        }
        SurfaceData sd = SurfaceData.getPrimarySurfaceData(img);
        return new SunGraphics2D(sd, Color.white, Color.black, defaultFont);
    }
```

We can clearly see that it uses the `defaultFont`, hardly *connected* to the image (unless `getPrimarySurface()` does change the `defaultFont` - I guess not [I could not find it being changed]).

Source code can be found [here](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk)

Setting the Font of a `Graphics` will not change anything in a `BufferedImage`. The `Font` is used by the `Graphics` to *draw* the text onto the image. If a new `Graphics` is obtained from the image (using `getGraphics()` or `createGraphics()`), it will have the `defaultFont` as defined in the `GraphicsEnvironment`.

Comment: I just figured it out. The information is actually saved in an `Graphics2D` object in two of the subclasses of `Graphics2D`. `SunGraphics2D` does not have this delegate object.

Comment: Two of the `Graphics2D` subtypes, `PeekGraphics` and `ProxyGraphics2D` have a delegate `Graphics2D` object which is where this is set. Unfortunately, access to that delegate is now forbidden because these classes are in the `sun` package.

Comment: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/faq-sun-packages.html

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(200, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 200, 100, null); // "this" refers to my custom JPanel which I am setting in the JFrame. 
g2d.setPaint(Color.red);
g2d.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
System.out.println("from g2d object: " + g2d.getFont().getFamily()); // outputs "Serif"
String s = "Hello, world!";
FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
int x = img.getWidth() - fm.stringWidth(s) - 5;
int y = fm.getHeight();
g2d.drawString(s, x, y);
System.out.println(g2d.getFont().toString()+"-"+img.getGraphics().getFont().toString()+" from image: " + img.getGraphics().getFont().getFamily());
g2d.dispose();
System.out.println("from image: " + img.getGraphics().getFont().getFamily());
```

As you can see g2d retains its beloved Serif notation. The image is a thing of itself. Each time you call createGraphics on the image you get a new thing.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone is making this more complicated than it needs to be.  The answer is quite simple:  the `getGraphics()` method of Image always creates a brand new Graphics object.  From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Image.html#getGraphics()):

> Creates a graphics context for drawing to an off-screen image.

That’s all there is to it.  You set the font in one Graphics object, then you created another Graphics object.  Of course the new Graphics object doesn’t know anything about the state of the first Graphics object.  That would be like expecting that turning on one car’s headlights could somehow cause all cars to turn on their headlights.

You can get the expected result by only calling getGraphics() **once.**

```
System.out.println("from image: " + g2d.getFont().getFamily());
```

Comment: You don't understand the problem. I ALREADY know that I can get that information from the graphics object. What I wanted was to obtain the same information from the image. I know now that it is not possible. The use case is for me to obtain data about the image (i.e. font color, font family, font face, etc.) at some point in the future; when the original `Graphics2D` object used to overlay the text in the image is no longer available. I can, from the image, get the color. I can't get the font information. That's all.

Comment: @hfontanez Ah, I see.  The answer is:  there is no way to recover that information.  Once you draw text, it is only retained as pixels;  the font knowledge is not retained by the image in any way.